# Open only numeric keyboard for a ASPX weppage application when call from iPhone/android? How to use html5 types in wepform?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, html

```
<input type="number" runat="server" id="numberonly"/> or <input type="tel" runat="server" id="numberonly"/>
```

will not work because its running on aspx wepform server, so parser error is coming. We cant use html5 type attributes in ASPX wepform application? Is there any way to set type attribute on load of page, using any plugin or javascript? I want to open only numeric keyboard while clicking on the textbox.

Comment: What makes you even think that? Check your code - it's **not** ASP.Net's "fault", more likely **your markup isn't correct**. What/where is your *doctype/html 5 declaration*?

Comment: @EdSF thanks man for your time ! but its not working! So i tried a alternate solution ! I've posted it below. My doctype like this<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: Please see [this intro to HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Introduction_to_HTML5?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML%2FHTML5%2FIntroduction_to_HTML5)

Comment: _"so parser error is coming"_ - what error?

Comment: It saying parser error if we use <input type="number" id="txtnumber" runat="server"/> because asp web forms not compatible with html5 type attribute. You need to upgrade your version of visual studio or you want to set type at run time using javascript like me! The Javascript is posted down is working and setting the type numer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can use like this, i found it somewhere.

```
 function setTypeNumeric() {

         document.getElementById('<%=myTextbox .ClientID%>').type = 'number';
     }
```

And in ASPX page we use like this

```
<input id="myTextbox" runat="server" />
```

This will set the type attribute on document ready. So no parser error will occur. We can use the HTML5 types in ASP.Net page control. Its working fine!!!

Comment: You are using the wrong [`doctype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Introduction_to_HTML5?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML%2FHTML5%2FIntroduction_to_HTML5)